# Why AEM returns 403 for requests without extensions?

Tags: aem, sling

By default all the GET requests go to DefaultGetServlet first. Based on the extension, it delegates the request to renderers. Now, if there is no extension in the request URI, why AEM sends 403 (Forbidden) ? At the most, if AEM is unable to serve this, it may send a BAD REQUEST instead. AEM sends 403 even if you are logged in as an admin user (Which has highest level of authorization, if that helps).

Example:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events
```

this URL will be responded with 403. Whereas

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events.html
```

will be served without any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to the above, as mentioned by Ahmed:
With the URL "http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events" `StreamRendererServlet` will get executed and resolves to [redirect logic](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.servlets.get/2.1.12/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/StreamRendererServlet.java#170) ending with `/`.

```
// redirect to this with trailing slash to render the index
String url = request.getResourceResolver().map(request,resource.getPath())+ "/";
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Once redirected to "http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events/"
The same `StreamRendererServlet` resolves to [directory listing logic](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.servlets.get/2.1.12/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/StreamRendererServlet.java#122).

```
// trailing slash on url means directory listing
if ("/".equals(request.getRequestPathInfo().getSuffix())) {
  renderDirectory(request, response, included);
  return;
}
```

In the `renderDirectory` as [indexing will be false](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.servlets.get/2.1.12/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/StreamRendererServlet.java/#320),

```
if (index) {
  renderIndex(resource, response);
} else {
  response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

a 403 Forbidden response will be sent.

You can change this behavior by enabling "Auto Index" for "Apache Sling GET Servlet" felix configuration console.

Answer (score 4):

As of this sling ticket [SLING-1231](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1231) closed in 2009, if no renderer is found the return status code should be 404.

you can see that in the sling sourcecode for `DefaultGetServlet.java` in the `doGet` method. [source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/DefaultGetServlet.java)

> The following tested on AEM 6.3 but *should* be the same for 6.0+

For example, if you tried to visit http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events.something you'd get a 404 and the sling progress tracker would log `No renderer for extension something`

Now, if I may rephrase your question, **why does extension=`null` return a 403?**

If you look at the sling progress tracker response, you'll probably notice this log:
`Using org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.helpers.StreamRendererServlet to render for extension=null`

Which means that for a `null` extension, Sling will use the `StreamRendererServlet`([source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/get/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/get/impl/helpers/StreamRendererServlet.java)) to try and render the resource. Somewhere in that code or probably a filter applied after causes the 403 response code you see. You'll have to debug that one yourself and find out where exactly a 403 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what [Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5633515/ahmed-musallam) said:

Without extension, Sling assumes that you are trying to list the contents of that directory path and looks for an index file under that path. When it doesn't finds that index file, it throws back the forbidden error.

If you add an index file under the `events` node and try to request the same extensionless url, it will serve that index file.
That is to say, when you add the index file (`index.html`) under `/content/geometrixx/en/events`, 
all requests to  `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events` or `http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events/index.html` will return the same result.

Comment: http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/events

with "index.html" under "events" node did not work for me.

Got the 403 error response with some clue,

`0 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/geometrixx/en/events', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='/'`

The suffix "/" should be doing something.